# Are there existing solutions for serving multiple websocket clients from a single upstream connection using a proxy server?

Tags: nginx, websocket, architecture, reverse-proxy, distributed-computing

I have a data vendor for real-time data that has a strict limit on the number of websocket connections I am allowed to make to their API. I have multiple microservices that need to consume this data, with some overlap in subscriptions. The clients do not need to communicate back anything beyond subscriptions.

I would like to design a system using a proxy-server that maintains a single websocket connection to the data vendor and then relays the appropriate messages to the clients via websocket. Optimally, the clients would be able to interact with the proxy server as if it were the data vendor's API.

I have looked at various (reverse?) proxy server solutions here, but have not found specific language about reducing the number of connections to the upstream data source. For example, I have looked into [NGINX](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html), but I can't tell if the proxy will combine client connections into a single upstream connection. The other solution I have researched is just putting all messages into a Kafka Pub/Sub via a connector, and have each client subscribe there.

I am curious if there are any existing, out of the box solutions to this problem before I implement my own solution.

Comment: can you please share if you have you found anything